# CMake find_library matching behavior?

Tags: cmake

One specifies `find_library(<var> name PATHS path1..pathn)`

My question is how does `find_library()` match name to the library file (on Windows and Linux)?

For example, I am unable to have `find_library()` identify the MagicK and MagicK++ DLL files in the provided Windows binary installation of GraphicsMagicK:

The files is: `CORE_RL_magick_.dll`

Searching for the queries: `magick` or `CORE_RL_magick` does not work.

Comment: Changing the file extension to lib enables cmake to identify it... What is the difference between dll and lib on windows?

Comment: This should be it's own question if you can't find it already on SO, but short answer is that the linker uses the .lib, and the .exe uses the .dll.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this documentation links:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:find_library

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES

find_library may accept one or more library names. Those names get the value of CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES prepended and CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES
 appended. This two variables should be set for each OS depending on how the librares are prefixed or suffixed there.

In your case I'd write for Windows

```
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES "")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".lib" ".dll")
```

and for Linux

```
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES "lib")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".so" ".a")
```

and then write

```
find_library(
    magick
    CORE_RL_magick_ (or NAMES if there are multiple names for the same library on different systems)

    PATHS
      path1
      path2
    ...
    (other options that are specified in documentation and would be usefull to you)
)
```

**EDIT:**

`CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES` and `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFIXES` are set automatically by [`project()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/project.html) so calling it first and `find_library()` after that point is a better solution than setting the variables manually.

Comment: If you want to link to it, you will need the `.lib` files. On Windows they are called "import library" and basically tell your linker about the exported symbols of your `.dll`. During execution, you will then (only) need the `.dll`

Comment: Additionally, be extra cautious about `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES` and `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES`! I've just stumbled into the library, which have set suffixes to ".dll.a" and I've been completely clueless about why `find_library` could not find any combination of "lib", "lib*.lib" and "*.a" files.

Comment: Also remember that Windows library vendors know Windows is case insensitive and like to provide libs in ALL CAPS, where cmake is case sensitive.  I had to use `SET( CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".lib" ".LIB" ".dll" ".DLL" ) to find all my libs.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `find_file()` instead of `find_library()` if you want to find a .dll.

Comment: Because I want to find the library on Linux and MS Windows.