# CMake's find_library cannot find library without version, extension and lib prefix

Tags: cmake

I am trying to link against a system library: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4`, when I have this CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)
project(all)

find_library(TCMALLOC_LIB NAMES tcmalloc)
if(TCMALLOC_LIB)
   message("Found TCMALLOC_LIB: ${TCMALLOC_LIB}")
else()
   message(FATAL_ERROR "TCMALLOC_LIB library not found")
endif()
```

(also tried `find_library(TCMALLOC_LIB tcmalloc)`)

I get

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (message):
  TCMALLOC_LIB library not found
```

While, if I have

```
find_library(TCMALLOC_LIB NAMES libtcmalloc.so.4)
```

everything is fine: `Found TCMALLOC_LIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4`

Am I doing something wrong? Why do I need to specify filename precisely? How can I debug `find_library`?

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?" - As usual, for create application which uses the library you need to install appropriate `-dev` package, which provides `libtcmalloc.so` symlink and header files.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I was thinking `-dev` library would been installed as a dependency of `libgoogle-perftools4`, but it is not true. I will update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but just in case it might be useful for someone: I had a similar problem (not related to a dev package) and I solved it with SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES "") which I found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14248656

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update - Real cause

As @Tsyvarev mentioned in the comment, it turns out that cmake could not find the library because I installed it only "partially", the `-dev` version (`libgoogle-perftools-dev`) should have been installed.

---

#### TL;DR

Well, it turns out that `tcmalloc` is not a regular/conventional library, namely, it does not have `libtcmalloc.so` symlink pointing to `.so.4`, that is why cmake cannot find it.

#### How can I debug `find_library`?

I found a way of debugging `find_library` via `strace`:

```
$ rm -rf ./* && strace cmake ../scripts/ 2>&1 | grep tcmalloc
access("/usr/local/nvidia/bin/libtcmalloc.so", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/local/cuda/bin/libtcmalloc.so", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/local/sbin/libtcmalloc.so", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/local/bin/libtcmalloc.so", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
<many lines skipped>
...
```

From this `strace` output we see that cmake, indeed **tries** to prepend `lib` and append `.so`, but it does not try to prepend any version.

Now, if we look at another "normal" library:

```
# locate protobuf | grep "\.so"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.17
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.17.0.0
```

we will see that it DOES install `.so` symlink, while `tcmalloc` does not:

```
# locate tcmalloc | grep "\.so"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4.3.0
```

Comment: I have the same problem in OSX i did install gperftools with `brew install gperftools` and cmake gives me `Found GooglePerfTools: /usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc.dylib` but my make fails saying `ld: library not found for -ltcmalloc` what can i do?